# Segue to a subclass of some view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm using a storyboard. Let's say I have a view controller that's named `MYviewController`.

In `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;` I would like to substitute the view controller that I'm segueing to, by one of its child, for example: `MYviewControllerChild1` OR `MYviewControllerChild2`. The child that's segued to depends on the `sender` parameter.

These view controllers have the same scene (in the storyboard). Only their behaviour is slightly different.

I have a tableView that shows the user the settings of the application. When he clicks a cell, it segues to a viewController where he can modify the value of some setting. Some of theses are alphanumeric, others are numeric. Depending on which cell is clicked, I'd like the input viewController to format the value accordingly (if it's a decimal value I'll use a NSNumberFormatter for example).

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Besides, I suspect you are using the sender parameter for something it is not supposed to. Am I correct in assuming sender isn't actually the sender, but you are (mis)using it for passing some other value?

Most likely, you should rethink the structure. Why are you using two separate controllers who are only slightly different? Explain the scenario and what's different, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: So... why are you using separate child implementations of a viewcontroller for this?

Comment: In `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]]`

Comment: Code would be cleaner (no if else)

Comment: Seems to me you could use one inputviewcontroller for this. You could test for the type of value coming from the tableview and then format it accordingly. If you created a separate viewcontroller every time you have only slight variations in the handling, while everything else is the same, it would only clutter the code.

Comment: Precision, it's not for formatting the value after the inputViewController did appear but while the user is modifying the value.

Comment: You're probably right saying that making childs will clutter the code even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments to your OP, I believe you should handle this kind of scenario in one viewcontroller.

However, if you insist on using separate controllers, maybe because you think the functionality will be expanded later down the line and therefore add more diversity, you need to handle this by creating multiple storyboard scenes - one for each child controller.

The destination view controller in prepareForSegue is imposed by the viewcontroller at the end of the segue in the storyboard. I don't think there is any way to override that.

Answer (score 0):

As described, your problem isn't really a good candidate for a storyboard.  If you use a storyboard you will have to create and sync multiple scenes.  Several possible solutions::

1. Create multiple storyboard scenes and invoke them manually via performSegueWithIdentifier.
2. Use a nib file instead of a storyboard for this scene.  You can use a single nib file since the view controller is created outside the storyboard with `[[VCClass alloc] initWithNibFile: bundle:`  You can create the appropriate view controller class and pass the same nib file to all instances.
3. Use a single storyboard scene and view controller and pass in typing information in your prepareForSegue.